# Remove page title on the attachment page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am really quite new to programming and I need help with something that I think is not difficult. What I want is to delete the title of the attachment page, I have searched and in this forum I have found a code that has worked partially. That is, the code removes the title but also removes the menu from the attachment page. I have searched everywhere, and I have seen that conditional tags are required to generate that function, however, I am a beginner in the world of websites and I need your help. The code is the following:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'remove_page_title', 10, 2 );

function remove_page_title( $title, $id ) {
     if (is_attachment())
        return '';

    return $title;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you post what do you expect? and what are you getting now?

Comment: Hello, I only want to remove the title of all the pages of attachments, but when applying the previous code, it eliminates the title and the menu. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your child theme you would add this into the functions.php file:

```
function remove_page_title( $title, $id ) {
  if (is_attachment()):
    return '';
    return $title;
  endif;
}
remove_action('virtue_page_title_container', 'remove_page_title', 20);
```

I hope it would help you out.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your quick answer, I appreciate that. I applied the code in my functions.php of my child theme in all the ways that occurred to me but it didn't work. These are the classes that are defined in my oni theme:
gt3_header_builder__container (where is the menu that I don't want to delete)

gt3-page-title_wrapper (where the title I want to delete is contained)

gt3-page-title__content (the title). Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Does gt3-page-title_wrapper is the class of the div?

Comment: Hi... yes, it is the class of the div.